# nginx 30 seconds 502 error timeout after proxy restart

Tags: nginx

I have many nodejs proxies running behind nginx, it has worked fine for years with 1 annoying exception.

When the nodejs process is restarted, the client receives a 502 error, which is OK, however nginx appears to continue refusing the connection for exactly 30 seconds, and then the connection is restored.

I need to reduce this down to a few seconds, I have seen other posts about increasing timeouts to overcome intermittent gateway errors, however this is different.

I have tried enabling keep-alive with:

```
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

But that has no effect.

Does anyone know which parameter is controlling this 30 second timeout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved:

```
proxy_cache_valid 502 5s;
```

This appears to reduce the time that the server waits after a 502 error before restoring the connection.